# Django Rest Framework get params inside has_permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm filtering real estates queryset dependent on user status and district (last one with GET param).

In views.py I have this:

```
class RealEstateView(APIView):
    serializer_class = RealEstateSerializer
    permission_classes = [RealEstatePermission]

    def get(self, request):
        district = self.request.query_params.get('pk')
        if district:
            serializer = RealEstateSerializer(RealEstate.objects.filter(owner_id=district), many=True)
        else:
            serializer = RealEstateSerializer(RealEstate.objects.all(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If user is superuser, he have access to all information. If user in not superuser, he can get access only to real estates from district which he is responsible. If user is responsible to district with `id=1`, but sends a get param with `id=2`, I need to raise an exception. But the problem is I don't know how to get access to get parameter in `has_permission` function. Doing this inside views get function seems not good idea.

I already tried `request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('id')` and `view.kwargs.get('id')`, both of them are empty.

in permissions.py:

```
class RealEstatePermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.is_staff:
                return True

            ## HERE I need something like request.user.district.id == kwargs('id')
            if request.user.role == 'district_municipality':
                return True
```

Using Django 3.0.5 and DRF 3.11.0.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to raise an exception? Mb you should not get district by `get params` and get them by yourself on backend? You have a user object that made the request and you can get his district ease. If the user is superuser you can allow him all

Comment: @AndreyRF, there are additional users category that can get access to data for read-only purposes. They are not superusers, but they can filter data by district.
I'm just trying to avoid if-else conditions in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get access to get parametersfrom url query you can use `GET` dict.

Example

url:

```
/district?id=2
```

access:

```
district_id = request.GET['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well:

```
Url:
/district?id=2
Access:
district_id = view.kwargs['id']
```